# User left answer in comments, never came back

Tags: support, answers, comments

I have a post here: [VS 2015 MVC OutOfMemoryException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35531994/vs-2015-mvc-outofmemoryexception)

Where user Graham added a comment which worked me to the answer.  I left a followup comment myself asking him to create an answer accordingly and I'd mark it as such, but he never came back.

What to do?  I don't necessarily want to post the answer myself, mark it, and get credit when it was really his, but I don't want to leave the unanswered question behind either.

Comment: You can self-answer your question and just give credits to him, when he doesn't want to post an answer.

Comment: In the suggestions he gave, there seems to be another Stack Answer. Shouldn't that mean your question is in fact a duplicate?

Comment: the one that worked for me was buried away in a blog post - there's numerous SO q/a's on the topic, but mine didn't fit with anything I'd found previously

Comment: Fair enough. I was just asking since I saw the stack link in Graham's comment. I didn't look further than that.

Comment: I'd suggest submitting an answer yourself. If you're worried about gaining reputation for an answer you didn't come up with yourself, you can mark it as a wiki-answer, and your reputation won't be affected.

Comment: If he wanted to take the time, he could have answered.  People often drop hints in comments if they have an idea, but don't want to spend the time fleshing it out.  If you want to thank him, provide a good answer that details what you did (with steps and images, if helpful) to fix your problem.  In your case, it appears you were eating 4+ gigs of memory, but not incorrectly, so x64 was the correct solution. How did you determine the memory usage wasn't a leak or in error?  Include that information as well.

Comment: I suppose I could have answered with that.

Comment: I often answer certain questions as comment and not as answer when I think that the question is on the one hand off topic, but I see that the OP is at a loss.

Comment: @jdl134679 you are a really nice guy.I appreciate your attutude. best of luck for your future.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You gave him the option to post an answer; that was nice of you. He obviously declined (or was unable to respond within a reasonable amount of time), so you should post an answer of your own.

I can't speak to what's in his mind, but I can say what would be in mine, since I do the same thing relatively often. The person who asks the question and *solves the problem* is in a better position to post a quality answer than I am. I just had an idea and pointed your thinking in the right direction. If I knew enough to post a good answer (or had the time to do so), I would have already done it. You, however, have followed my lead, solved the problem, and have an even better understanding of the situation. Perfect for writing a good answer. Everyone wins.

Don't feel compelled to mark the answer you submit as community wiki in order to surrender the reputation gained, or anything like that. Not only is that an abuse of the community wiki feature, but it simply isn't necessary. You have *earned* the reputation! You did the research/debugging, thought about the issue, solved the problem, and wrote the answer. If others find that answer helpful, you deserve the upvotes they give it.

It would, however, be appropriate to give Graham some credit for pointing you in the right direction. The top of your answer might mention his comment, the relevant link(s), and his name. You know, the standard attribution rules. I would be more than content with that myself.

Answer (score 1):

Well the user in question ***did come back*** but probably didn't want to answer the question or didn't see the comment you posted.

In my case as the OP (assume I am), I would answer the question myself with attribution to the commented. Usually use this `>` followed by the comment word for word followed by `- username_here`. This explains to the users and other people the answer came from this comment and the credit goes to that user. Giving yourself the mark doesn't give you any rep except for the upvotes.

Anyways, don't hold up and answer the question mentioning that user plus his comment word for word to accredit him. If he does come back and answers the question, you can accept that answer if you choose. The answer you make should not come solely from the comment, make your own and add some other information that the user didn't mention in his comment.